# Determining $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times\mathbb{Z}_{5}).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The way I attempted to solve it was to use the fact that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \cong U(3) \times U(4) \times U(5) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. However, we technically were not allowed to use this fact. So, I was wondering how one could solve this just from knowing that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \cong \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{60}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{60}^{\times}?$ I'm guessing one could just write out the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{60}^{\times}$ by hand and solve it that way, but is there a faster way than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** If $f \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_5)$ then
$$f(1,0,0) \mbox{ has order } 3 \\
f(0,1,0) \mbox{ has order } 4 \\
f(0,0,1) \mbox{ has order } 5$$